# How to rotate tank body towards movement direction like in Wii Tanks - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I'm trying to make tank movement like in [Wii Tanks](https://youtu.be/48L9-_laUP8?t=222). I  can't figure out how to rotate the tank in the direction of movement. The rotation would only be on the y-axis so the tank doesn't start flipping out.

```
    moveDir = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    moveDir = transform.TransformDirection(moveDir);
    controller.Move(moveDir * Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

This is my code for moving the tank so now I just need it to rotate. Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: You can use transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDir);

Comment: What did you tried so far? Check the Oficial Documentation. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html