# Unity 3D instantly rotate in the direction of movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, game-physics, euler-angles

I have a somewhat similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56051903/how-to-rotate-tank-body-towards-movement-direction-like-in-wii-tanks-unity), I'm trying to rotate in the direction of movement but the issue is that I want to maintain my position and just instantly rotate because I have a procedural maze and there's not enough space to gradually swing around in the direction of movement in a wide turn. I'll post code attempts at the bottom, attempt two gives the error: viewing vector is zero.

If you look at all four of these screenshots, when the y-axis is rotated, the x-axis and z-axis jump to a new position. When I'm moving this ends up looking like I'm teleporting around the maze. Anyone know how to rotate while remaining in the same position?

Here's right:
[image]

Here's forward:
[image]

Here's left:
[image]

Here's back:
[image]

here's code attempt 1:

```
public void playerMovement()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movementx = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0f, 0f);
        Vector3 movementy = new Vector3(0f, 0f, verticalInput);
      
        movementy = transform.forward * verticalInput;
        movementx = transform.right * horizontalInput;

        if (horizontalInput > 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 90f, 0f);
            transform.Translate(-movementx.normalized * 0.1f, Space.Self);
        }

        if (horizontalInput < 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 270f, 0f);
            transform.Translate(-movementx.normalized * 0.1f, Space.Self);
        }

        if (verticalInput < 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 180f, 0f);
            transform.Translate(movementy.normalized * 0.1f, Space.Self);
        }

        if (verticalInput > 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
            transform.Translate(movementy.normalized * 0.1f, Space.Self);
        }
    }
```

Here's code attempt 2:

```
    public void playerMovement2()
    {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);
        transform.Translate(movement.normalized * 0.1f, Space.Self);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movement);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your second attempt and modified it:

This way you will walk and look in the direction you

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

    transform.Translate(movement.normalized * 0.1f, Space.World);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movement, Vector3.up);

}
```

However then the character will always "flip" back to forward
-> you can solve that by only moving when new input is given

For example like this:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

    if (movement.magnitude > 0f)
    {
        transform.Translate(movement.normalized * 0.1f, Space.World);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movement, Vector3.up);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's still teleporting, when moving forwards and backwards the Z-axis jumps from 1.424429 to -0.6240578, and left to right the X-axis jumps from 2.240456 to 2.640643. But it's slightly better, mine had both z-axis and x-axis jumping when I turned. It's like there's an invisible ball and I'm pivoting around it unable to just spin without moving

Comment: is it possible that you have your script on a "GameObject A" which is a parent of "GameObject B" -> and while the script is on "GameObject A"; the visual part of your character is on the child "GameObject B" + this "GameObject B" has offset (when you click it the position isn't (0, 0, 0) ?

if yes then put the GameObject B (with the visuals) at position (0, 0, 0) [relative to it's parent "GameObject A" -with the script]

Comment: yes thank you, I just realized the blender model of the robot in the hierarchy is 3 different nested parts: "Player", "Robot Controller", and "Body" so what was happening was everything wasn't centered in the same position: 0,0,0 and that threw off the rotation, thanks!